# Append a custom AngularJS directive on ng-click to a container HTML element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have a following problem: I have a complicated custom directive, that is used to recursively get info about input fields from our `RESTful WS`. I'd like to append this directive using `ng-click` to an HTML element, which wraps current `<button>`.
Please, take a look at the `appendDirective` function. This is the one that should append a directive to a parent element, which called it.

Directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('recursiveFields', function ($compile, $http) {
        return {
            scope: {
                field: '=field',
                model: '=model'
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            controller: "httpPostController",
            template: '<div ng-repeat="nestedField in field.nestedFields"><div ng-show="{{!nestedField.isEntity && !nestedField.isEnum}}">' + '<p ng-show={{nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}*: </p>' + '<p ng-show={{!nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}: </p>' + '<input type="text" ng-model="model[nestedField.name]" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()"' + 'class="form-control" placeholder="{{parseClassName(nestedField.type)}}">' + '</div>' + '<div ng-show="{{nestedField.isEnum}}">' + '<p ng-show={{nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}*: </p>' + '<p ng-show={{!nestedField.isRequired}}>{{nestedField.name}}: </p>' + '<select ng-model="model[nestedField.name]" ng-change="getCreateEntityAsText()" class="form-control">' + '<option></option>' + '<option ng-repeat="enumValue in nestedField.enumValues" label={{enumValue.name}}>{{enumValue.ordinal}}</option>' + '</select>' + '</div>' +

            '<div ng-show="{{nestedField.restResourceName != null}}">' + '<accordion close-others="oneAtATime">' + '<accordion-group heading={{nestedField.name}} is-open="false">' + /*'<recursive-fields model="createEntityResource" field="field"></recursive-fields>'*/
            '<button type="button" ng-click="appendDirective()">I should append a "recursiveFields" directive</button>' + '</accordion-group>' + '</accordion>' + '</div>' + '</div>',

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                console.log("1");
                if (scope.field.restResourceName != null) {
                    $http.get(CONSTANTS.EXPLAIN_URL + "/" + scope.field.restResourceName).success(function (data, status) {
                        scope.field.nestedFields = [];
                        data.content.resource.fields.forEach(function (field) {
                            if (field.isEnum) {
                                $http.get(CONSTANTS.ENUMS_URL + scope.$root.parseClassName(field.type)).success(function (data, status) {
                                    field.enumValues = [];
                                    for (var index in data.content.values) {
                                        field.enumValues.push(data.content.values[index]);
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                            scope.field.nestedFields.push(field);
                        })
                    })
                }

                scope.appendDirective = function () {
                    var newDir = angular.element('<recursive-fields model="createEntityResource" field="field"></recursive-fields>');
                    $compile(newDir.contents())(scope);
                    alert("Done");
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

Basically, it looks like this: After pressing `<button>` **1**, the content of `<div>` **2** should have nested directive, just like in `<div>` **3**. In other words, the directive should be appended to the parent of **1** (element **2**).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Every useful answer is highly appreciated and evaluated.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$scope.appendDirective = function () {
  var recursiveFields = $("<recursive-fields />");
  recursiveFields.attr("aParam", "aValue");
  recursiveFields.insertAfter(yourButton);
  $compile(recursiveFields)($scope);
}
```

And in html:

```
<button ng-click="appendDirective()">Your Button</button>
```

Your controller must inject $compile:

```
myApp.controller("myController", $compile) {
}
```

Comment: This works, but one more thing's left. How can I detect which element called the function?

P.S. This function is defined within a directive, not in a controller. Just for unknown reason I can't access it from controller.

Comment: You can pass the name of the element to the function: appendDirective("button01").